# Is there a standard abbreviation for 'find . -name foo' or do I need a function for this?

Tags: bash, shell, find

I recently used `find . -name some-file-name` a lot and decided that it's time to abbreviate this with a function (`fb` stands for find below):

```
function fb() {
  find . -name "$1"
}
```

This seems to work as intended. Still, I'd like to know if there is a more standard way to achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining aliases or functions to simplify commands you use often **is** the standard way. I don't know of any built-in function or command to do this same thing, provided as standard on most Linux and Unix-type systems. There are undoubtedly similar aliases or functions in pre-packaged collections; for example, [Oh My Zsh](http://ohmyz.sh/)'s [common-aliases plugin](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/common-aliases/common-aliases.plugin.zsh) defines `fd` and `ff` which are similar to your function:

```
alias fd='find . -type d -name'
alias ff='find . -type f -name'
```

Comment: Yes, I agree, but I thought that maybe there is already a built-in function or command that  does the same thing, given my assumption that this construct is exectued many times by many other users.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, but you'll find similar commands in pre-packaged collections of helper tools; see my update.